Flutter - CachedNetworkImage reloading in a carousel
I'm currently working on developing an app using Flutter. The home page of the app includes a carousel that should scale up the item currently being viewed by the user. The carousel items consist of images.
I'm utilizing the carousel_slider package for the carousel and the cached_network_image package for displaying the images.
To see a video of my app in action, click here. In the video, you'll notice that the images reload.
Here's the code for my carousel:
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:traveller/components/my_city_card.dart';
import 'package:traveller/utilities/provider/my_passive_provider.dart';

class MyCityCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCityCarousel({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: CarouselSlider.builder(
        itemCount: Provider.of<MyPassiveProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .cities
            .length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
          return MyCityCard(index: index);
        },
        options: CarouselOptions(
          aspectRatio: 1,
          viewportFraction: 0.75,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          enlargeFactor: 0.25,
          autoPlay: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

In my code, 'MyCityCard' is defined like this :
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:traveller/components/my_button.dart';
import 'package:traveller/utilities/provider/my_passive_provider.dart';

class MyCityCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const MyCityCard({
    super.key,
    required this.index,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyPassiveProvider>(
      builder: (context, provider, _) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // Background
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                          provider.cities[index]["image"]),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Effet vignette
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9 * 0.325,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
                            top: Radius.circular(50.0)),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Colors.grey[900]!.withOpacity(0.5),
                            Colors.transparent,
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9 * 0.25,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
                            bottom: Radius.circular(50.0)),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Colors.grey[900]!.withOpacity(0.5),
                            Colors.transparent,
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          end: Alignment.topCenter,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                // Content
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          // Nom de la ville
                          Text(
                            provider.cities[index]["name"],
                            style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                              fontSize:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.075,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),

                          // Prix
                          Text(
                            provider.cities[index]["price"] == null
                                ? "GRATUIT"
                                : "${(provider.cities[index]["price"]).toString().padRight(4, "0")}€",
                            style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                              fontSize:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

                      // Bouton acheter / possédé
                      MyButton(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7 * 0.9,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9 * 0.1,
                        borderRadius: 25.0,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 1.5,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        text: provider.cities[index]["price"] == null
                            ? "Possédé"
                            : "Acheter",
                        textStyle: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

(the important part of this component is the Container right under the comment // Background)
My goal is to have the images load only once and then remain displayed until the user closes the app. To provide a comparison, I'd like the CarouselSlider to behave as if it were a ListView with the cacheExtent argument set to double.infinity or double.maxFinite.
Thanks in advance for your help, and happy coding!

Are you sure that there is a network call going second time?

What happens if you use the default constructor instead of CarouselSlider.builder? According to docs the CarouselSlider.builder builds the widgets only when needed while the CarouselSlider constructor does build all items.

I updated my code by replacing CarouselSlider.builder with CarouselSlider, but the issue remains unchanged with no improvement.

Did you use cacheManager in CacheNetworkImage ?

I specified CachedNetworkImageProvider.defaultCacheManager for cacheManager, but the result remains the same and I don't see any reason to specify a custom cacheManager. By the way, I have updated my question and included the code for my component MyCityCard so that you have more elements to help me solve this issue.
